# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, oracle, hikaricp

I have a problem with Hikari conntect to Oracle.

JDK1.7, hikari-java1.7, oracle11 with ojdbc6.

```
<bean id="slave-hikari" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hikari.driverClassName}" /> 
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${slave.datasource.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${slave.datasource.username}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${slave.datasource.password}"/> 
</bean>
```

Here are exceptions:

```
2017-07-31 18:22:11,848 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter WARN  - SQL 

Error: 0, SQLState: null
2017-07-31 18:22:11,848 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter ERROR - 
2017-07-31 18:22:11,851 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory WARN  - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:137)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:428)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:499)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97)
```